# Poor quality image inserting SVG into PDF

Tags: c#, svg

I'm trying to generate a PDF containing some text, a logo and a barcode. Everything is OK except for the quality of the logo.

For the sake of providing an example I'm using this [SVG](https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/dojo.svg).

The logo is generated using [svg.Net](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG) as follows:

```
SvgDocument svgDoc = SvgDocument.Open<SvgDocument>(@"C:\temp\SVG\dojo.svg");
svgDoc.Width = 130;
svgDoc.Height = 30;
var bmp = svgDoc.Draw();
```

This is then drawn onto a [PrintDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) as follows:

```
Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, logoLeft, logoTop);
```

Before finally being sent to a PDF printer driver. The end results is a fuzzy looking logo at 100% zoom

[image: Generated PDF]

Zooming in on the PDF and the logo resolution is really low

[image: Zoomed in Logo]

How can I improve the quality of the final output?

Comment: What do you this `svgDoc.Width = 130;` to do? set the width to what? Pixels? some other unit without setting a resolution? Obviously you need to draw onto a much larger bitmap and then set its dpis before drawing it into the printdocument..!

Comment: Also: How did you set the printing resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working by skipping out the process of creating an intermediary PNG which I could not get displaying nicely.

Using a different method of the `svg.net` and writing directly to the graphics object.

The step

```
Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, logoLeft, logoTop);
```

Has been replaced with

```
svgDoc.X = logoLeft;
svgDoc.Y = logoTop;
svgDoc.Draw(Graphics);
```

Comment: Nice, although I would definitely recommend learning how to properly work with image and printer resolutions..